# Using push_back for vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am having trouble using push_back for vectors in c++.

My vector is named `data`.

In my loop I want to add `50` to `data[i].getQuantity` then `push_back` to `data`

These are things that I have tried.

```
    data.push_back(data[i].getQuantity());
```

and

```
   float myFloat = data[i].getQuantity() + 50;
   data.push_back(data[i].getQuantity(myFloat));
   data.push_back(myFloat);
```

The error is saying

> No function to call to push_back

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


struct Input
{
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& inp, Input& item);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outp, Input const& item);

    std::string group;
    std::string total_pay;
    float quantity;

    // default constructor. sets up zero-elements
    Input() : group(), total_pay(), quantity()
    {
    }

    Input(std::string groupIn, std::string total_payIn, float quantityIn) :
    group(std::move(groupIn)),
    total_pay(total_payIn),
    quantity(quantityIn)
    {
    }

    // Accessors
    std::string const& getGroup() const { return group; }
    std::string getTotalPay() const { return total_pay; }
    float getQuantity() const { return quantity; }
};

// global free function for extracting an Input item from an input stream
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& inp, Input& item)
{
    return (inp >> item.group >> item.total_pay >> item.quantity);
}

// global operator for inserting to a stream
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outp, Input const& item)
{
    outp
    << item.getGroup() << ", "
    << item.getTotalPay() << ", "
    << item.getQuantity();
    return outp;
}

struct ctype : std::ctype<char>
{
    static mask* make_table()
    {
        static std::vector<mask> table(classic_table(),
                                       classic_table() + table_size);
        table[','] |= space;
        return &table[0];
    }

    ctype() : std::ctype<char>(make_table()) { }
};

int main() {
    std::fstream infile("employee.dat");
    std::vector<Input> data;
    std::string line;

    try {
    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {

        std::istringstream iss(line);
        Input inp;
        iss.imbue(std::locale(iss.getloc(), new ctype));

        while (iss >> inp) // calls our extraction operator >>
            data.push_back(inp);

        if (iss.fail() && !iss.eof())
            std::cerr << "Invalid input line: " << line << '\n';
    }

    // dump all of them to stdout. calls our insertion operator <<
              std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<Input>(std::cout,"\n"));

    std::ofstream outp("output.dat");

        for(int i = 0; i < data[i].getQuantity(); i++)
        {

            float myFloat = data[i].getQuantity() + 50;
            data.push_back(myFloat);
            outp << data[i].getGroup() << ',' << data[i].getTotalPay() << ',' << data[i].getQuantity() + 50 << '\n';
        }

    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "There was an error: " << '\n';

        return 1;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want `emplace_back()` rather than `push_back()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your vector is of type `std::vector<Input>`. That means you can only put objects of type `Input` into it. You can't `push_back` a `float` into such a vector.

If your intention is to create a new `Input` object and push that back into your vector, you could do something like

```
data.push_back(Input(data[i].getGroup(), data[i].getTotalPay(), data[i].getQuantity() + 50))
```

On the other hand, if you are simply trying to modify an element in `data` without adding a new element to data, you could just do

```
data[i].quantity += 50;
```

This works because you use a `struct` rather than a class. In a struct, variables default privacy level is `public`. If you wanted to use a class, or you just don't want to directly access the struct members, you would have to create a setter function for quantity.

Comment: ohhhh ok god that makes sense. So because I am doing it as object I need to push back a object. Is it possible to add 50 as I want and create a object to push back then? What would be the logical way to handle this?

Comment: @NDiaz Well you haven't shown your `Input` class definition, so I don't really know what you can do with that. If you show that class definition, I could try to help.

Comment: @NDiaz Now that you have added your `Input` code, could you say what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You could look into adding a conversion constructor for floats to your `Input` class. Then you could do `data.push_back(Input(data[i].getQuantity() + 50.f));` or if you supplied this operator overload: `const Input Input::operator+(const float) const`, you could do `data.push_back(data[i] + 50.f);`

Comment: @NDiaz Are you trying to `push_back` a new Input object with the same group and total_pay but different quantity, or are you just trying to change the quantity of an Input object that is already in the vector?

Comment: @iwolf TAing has allowed me to recognize mappings of (things novice programmers do) -> (things novice programmers are trying to do) that regular professional software developers might never think of.

Comment: @NDiaz I have updated my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: My goal is to add 50 and then just use push_back to replace it back into the vector. I want to replace the object so I can then output it to a file. I have no problem getting the rest done I just cant get pushback to work.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to make the constructor to allow data.push_back(data[i].getQuantity() + 50) to work.

Comment: @NDiaz See my updated answer. If you use push_back, then after you do it, you will have _two_ elements in the vector: the original one, and the one that is + 50. Based on your comment, it seems like that is not what you want. You just want to update the `Input` object that is already in the vector.

Comment: On the new updated answer my error is no matching conversion from float to Input. So I am assuming I can using something similar to atoi but for float to object?

Comment: Well I need to update the object and send it back to the vector. Your recent answer creates a new object I thought? Also when I use the code you show me it tells me there is no matching conversion for float to Input.

Comment: @NDiaz Use _either_ the first code snippet _or_ the second. You said you just want to modify, so use the second, not the first. You don't want to be using `push_back` here at all. When you modify it, you are modifying it in place. You never "take it out" of the vector, so you don't have to "send it back". If you are still getting the same error, please post your updated code.